# Режим Direct Boot и доступ к базе данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Как получить доступ к базе данных (SQLite или ROOM), когда смартфон находится в режиме Direct Boot?
Моя цель - заново включить все активные будильники (взяв их данные из БД) после перезагрузки, не дожидаясь разблокирования смартфона пользователем.

Документация([Режим Direct Boot](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot?hl=ru#access)) показывает доступ к данным на примере SharedPreferences и лишь мельком упоминаются базы данных.

Официальный пример ([GitHub](https://github.com/android/security-samples/tree/master/DirectBoot)) так же строится вокруг SharedPreferences. Нагуглить что-то, что помогло бы решить мою проблему не вышло - информации почти нет.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct Boot по сути означает, что данные приложения теперь можно хранить в 2-х ипостасях:

1. *Credential Encrypted Storage* (CES) - традиционное место хранения данных приложения, где то в `/data/data/[package]/` - данные зашифрованы с использованием логина юзера
2. *Device Encrypted Storage* (DES) - место хранения данных, где данные зашифрованы с использованием данных самого устройства

Исходя из этого вам надо поместить свою БД SQLite/ROOM в DES хранилище и тогда и только тогда ее данные будут доступны в режиме Direct Boot.

```
 Context cesContext = context.getApplicationContext(); //обычный CES контекст
 Context desContext = ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext(cesContext); //DES контекст, доступный в Direct Boot
```

Вам надо положить свою БД не в `cesContext` как обычно, а в `desContext`, тогда он будет доступен в режиме Direct Boot